# Вырявнять textarea с input по одной линии

Tags: html, css

Ничего не понимаю в вёрске, привязал python скрипт к страничке, хотелось бы что бы выглядело хотя бы ровно всё. Сейчас нижняя часть input чуть ниже чем нижняя часть textarea. Как их выровнять что бы они на одной линии пикселей были.
Есть вот такая форма:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/form9.py" method="post">
    <textarea name = "textmac" rows="5" cols="3">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit"> <small>Добавить</small>
</form>
```

И вот такой css:

```
<style>
textarea, input, select{
    width:130px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в стилях задать одинаковую высоту.

Если надо, чтобы кнопка тянулась по высоте textarea, то можно так:

```css
textarea, input, select{
    width:130px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
display: flex
}
```

```html
<form action="/cgi-bin/form9.py" method="post" class="form">
    <textarea name = "textmac" rows="5" cols="3">
    </textarea>
    <button type="submit"> <small>Добавить</small></button>
</form>
```

Прижимаем к низу:

```css
textarea, input, select{
    width:130px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<form action="/cgi-bin/form9.py" method="post" class="form">
    <textarea name = "textmac" rows="5" cols="3">
    </textarea>
    <button type="submit"> <small>Добавить</small></button>
</form>
```

Comment: если делать как у вас кнопка во весь размер, то да, всё становится ровно, но хотелось бы еще попробовать, что бы кнопка не во весь размер была, а просто была дефолтная по размеру, но при этом не опускалась, как сейчас, чуть ниже чем textarea. Сейчас почему то смещение на пару пикселе вниз.

Comment: @sakhalin можно добавить .form {
display: flex; align-items: flex-end
}

Comment: похоже) только теперь между textarea и button  расстояние меньше чем у на других форм) как туда поставить дополнительный пиксель?))

Comment: @sakhalin Когда вы в коде строчный элемент переносите на новую строку, то при отрисовке страницы этот перенос будет интерпретирован как пробел, поэтому либо пишите в коде input/button сразу после textarea без переноса, тогда пробела вообще не будет, либо вставьте в моем примере символ пробела между кнопкой и textarea. Вот он: &nbsp; Флекс контейнер съедает перенос, но символ не тронет.

Comment: Спасибо, вчера разобрался, пришлось действительно пользоваться &nbsp; и еще создавать новую .form для button =)